# Matrix including function handle

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am really as green as grass with mathlab, so sorry for dummy questions.

I have the following matrix:

[image]

Soo, how i can input function_handle into matrix? When i want to input that function into my matrix matlab is showing me an error

> $
>   A(1,1)=f
>   Conversion to double from function_handle is not possible.

And my second question, maybe it is related with first how i can determine the smalles value of alpha which will satisfy `det(A(alpha)) = 0` using Matlab?

My code right now:

```
N=10 
A=eye(N) 
f=@(x) 2^x - 2 
A(1,1) = f
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But my code is something like

N=10
A=eye(N)
f=@(x) 2^x - 2
A(1,1) = f

I just cant start without puting that f(x) into matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
N = 10;
alpha = 1;
f=@(x) 2^x - 2;
A(1,1) = f(alpha);
```

You have to give your function a argument, so it can evaluate to a double.

Comment: Yea, thanks a lot i just got that alpha can be something like this a=[-1000:1000] and i can implement the alpha into function :D Thanks a lot, that information about not using only scalar values were important thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you defined **f** to be, i assume you made it something like a (anonymous) function. So for the future, please provide a minimal code example, so other users can understand your problem better.

To the problem itself:

First of all you should know, that a matrix is a collection of values which need to be of the same **type**, in MatLab this usually will be **doubles**.

So for example you can say

```
A(1,1) = 12.3;
```

to define one value of the matrix to be 12.3, which is a double.

You can also assign multiple values, e.g.

```
A = [12.2, 23.3; -2.3, 4.2];
```

which will result in a 2x2 matrix of doubles. As you did not write indices after **A** you will define the whole matrix A, but not only parts of it, as you did with the first example.

What you are doing, when you execute

```
A(1,1) = f;
```

is to write **f** (whatever it is) to the matrix element in row 1 and column 1, as given by the indices.

And as **f** is a function handle and **A** is a matrix of double, you get this error message.

So basically you should have 2 options:

1. Give that function **f** a argument, so that it can evaluate to some double value (e.g. **f(2)**). This assumes, that your function evaluates to double.
2. Calculate the value inline, without using a function at all, e.g. you could easily do something like `A(1,1) = 42*sin(12*pi)+13)`

Hope this helps

Comment: Lets assume that my f is f(x)=2^x - 2. I know there is a way to do something like z=f(3) and then inject it to my matrix but my assingment is to determine the smallest value of x in f(x) which will be satisfying equation which i given earlier. Fastest method is something like just typing x and checking answer?

Comment: Functions are not restricted to only handle scalar values, e.g. you can define function giving back matrices. This is the whole trick with Matlab. So you need to perform 2 steps: Evaluate your function to a double value and building the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I thought to first simplify the matrix and then find an easier way to program it, but ended up with an analytical solution. Strictly speaking it might not belong here, but I'll post it anyway.

Since the determinant of a matrix is invariant if you add a multiple of a row/column to another, you can find the following expression for your determinant:

```
det(A) = 4^(N-1)*f(alpha)^2
```

where N is the dimension of the A.

Example for N = 4:

```
     f^2   -2f   2f   -2f
A =  -2f     8   -8     8
      2f    -8   12   -12
     -2f     8  -12    16
```

For each column (starting form column 2) add the next column:

```
     f^2    0   0   -2f
A =  -2f    0   0     8
      2f    4   0   -12
     -2f   -4   4    16
```

For each row (starting from the last one till the second (not included)) add the previous row:

```
     f^2    0   0   -2f
A =  -2f    0   0     8
       0    4   0    -4
       0    0   4     4
```

For columns 2 -> N-1 the first two rows are zero, if you consider `A(3:N,3:N)` this is a diagonal matrix with 4 on the diagonal.

For each row (except the first two), make the last column zero by adding or substracting the column with a 4 on the correct row. You then get:

```
     f^2    0   0   -2f
A =  -2f    0   0     8
       0    4   0     0
       0    0   4     0
```

Then determing the determinant:

```
                f^2    0   -2f
det(A) = 4*det( -2f    0     8  )
                  0    4     0


       = 16*det( f^2   -2f )
                 -2f     8
```

In general this will be

```
det(A) = 4^(N-2)*det( f^2   -2f )
                      -2f     8
```

because of the diagonal 4 sub-matrix. Since

```
det( f^2   -2f ) = 8*f^2-4*f^2 = 4*f^2
     -2f     8
```

we get

```
det(A) = 4^(N-1)*f^2
```

Substituting f:

```
det(A) = 4^(N-1)*(2^x - 2)^2
```

You need `det(A) = 0`, so

```
4^(N-1)*(2^x - 2)^2 = 0     =>    x = 1
```